# closures in swift are doing whatever. My code execution isn't acting as is supposed

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, swift2, nsjsonserialization

In app delegate, after to get the coordinates of the user with core location, I want to make two api calls. One is to my server, to get a slug of the city name in which we are. The call is async so I want to load all the content into a global variable array before make the second call to google maps api, to get the city name from google, also with an async call. And finally after I have loaded all the google data, I want to compare the two arrays, with the city names to find a coincidence. To do that, I need the first two operation to have ended. For this I'm using closures, to ensure all the data is loaded before the next operation start. But when I launch my program, it doesn't find any coincidence between the two arrays and when I set breakpoints, I see the second array (google) is loaded **after** the comparison is made, which is very frustrating because I've set a lot of closures, and at this stage I'm not able to find the source of my issue. Any help would be appreciated.

this is app delegate:

```
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    //Language detection
    let pre = NSLocale.preferredLanguages()[0]
    print("language= \(pre)")

    //Core Location
    // Ask for Authorisation from the User.
    self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

    //Clore Location
    // For use in foreground
    self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()


        //Load cities slug via api call
        let apiCall : webApi = webApi()

        apiCall.loadCitySlugs(){(success) in
            //Slug loaded in background
            //Call google api to compare the slug
            apiCall.loadGoogleContent(){(success) in //this function is called after compareGoogleAndApiSlugs()
                apiCall.compareGoogleAndApiSlugs() //this one called before
            }
        }

    }
    return true
}
```

This is my global variables swift file:

```
import Foundation
import CoreLocation
let weatherApiKey : String = "" //weather api key
var globWeatherTemp : String = ""
var globWeatherIcon : String = ""
var globCity : String = ""
var globCountry : String = ""
let googleMapsApiKey : String = ""
let googlePlacesApiKey : String = ""
var TableData:Array< String > = Array < String >()
var nsDict = []
var locValue : CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2D()


typealias SuccessClosure = (data: String?) -> (Void)
typealias FinishedDownload = () -> ()
typealias complHandlerAsyncCall = (success : Bool) -> Void
typealias complHandlerCitySlug = (success:Bool) -> Void
typealias complHandlerAllShops = (success:Bool) -> Void
typealias googleCompareSlugs = (success:Bool) -> Void

var flagCitySlug : Bool?
var flagAsyncCall : Bool?
var flagAllShops : Bool?

var values : [JsonArrayValues] = []
var citySlug : [SlugArrayValues] = []

var asyncJson : NSMutableArray = []
let googleJson : GoogleApiJson = GoogleApiJson()
```

this is the first function called in app delegate, which make a call to my server to load the city slug:

```
    func loadCitySlugs(completed: complHandlerCitySlug){

    //Configure Url
    self.setApiUrlToGetAllSlugs()

    //Do Async call
    asyncCall(userApiCallUrl){(success)in

        //Reset Url Async call and Params
        self.resetUrlApi()

        //parse json 
        self.parseSlugJson(asyncJson)

        flagCitySlug = true
        completed(success: flagCitySlug!)
    }
}
```

This is the second function, it load google content but it's called after compareGoogleAndApiSlugs() and it's supposed to be called before...

```
    /*
 Parse a returned Json value from an Async call with google maps api Url
 */
func loadGoogleContent(completed : complHandlerAsyncCall){

    //Url api
    setGoogleApiUrl()

    //Load google content
    googleAsyncCall(userApiCallUrl){(success) in

    //Reset API URL
    self.resetUrlApi()
    }
    flagAsyncCall = true // true if download succeed,false otherwise

    completed(success: flagAsyncCall!)
}
```

And finally the async calls, there are two but they are almost the same code:

```
    /**
 Simple async call.
 */
func asyncCall(url : String, completed : complHandlerAsyncCall)/* -> AnyObject*/{

    //Set async call params
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: url)!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    request.HTTPBody = postParam.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) { data, response, error in
        guard error == nil && data != nil else {
            // check for fundamental networking error
            print("error=\(error)")
            return
        }
        if let httpStatus = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse where httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {
            // check for http errors
            print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
            print("response = \(response)")
        }


        let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

        asyncJson = responseString!.parseJSONString! as! NSMutableArray

        flagAsyncCall = true // true if download succeed,false otherwise

        completed(success: flagAsyncCall!)

    }
    task.resume()

}
```

If anyone can see the issue or throw some light it would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this function:

```
func loadGoogleContent(completed : complHandlerAsyncCall){

    setGoogleApiUrl()
    googleAsyncCall(userApiCallUrl){(success) in

        self.resetUrlApi()
    }
    flagAsyncCall = true
    completed(success: flagAsyncCall!) //THIS LINE IS CALLED OUTSIDE THE googleAsyncCall..
}
```

The above completion block is called outside of the googleAsyncCall block.

The code should be:

```
func loadGoogleContent(completed : complHandlerAsyncCall){

    setGoogleApiUrl()
    googleAsyncCall(userApiCallUrl){(success) in

        self.resetUrlApi()
        flagAsyncCall = true
        completed(success: flagAsyncCall!)

    }
}
```

Btw.. your global variables are NOT atomic.. so be careful.

Comment: Sorry can you explain a bit more what can be the issue if the variable isn't atomic? I'm new in swift and this info can be very helpful for me. Also would like to ask you about the global variable completion handler, it has to be always global? Isn't there a way to do completion handlers with locals? Also would like to know if I can reuse those global variables? How can I set them to false again? And thanks a lot, cause your answer solved my issue!

Comment: If the variable isn't atomic and multiple threads are accessing it for writing at the same time, which state is the variable still in? Each thread might see a different value. No you don't always need global variables. In fact, you probably almost never ever need them. Yes you can reuse them.